# Different alignment of long doubles in a struct on 64 bit linux with gcc and clang

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64, memory-alignment

I noticed that gcc and clang compile the following code differently:

```
struct { long double ld[1]; } ld1;
struct { long double ld[2]; } ld2;
struct { long double ld[3]; } ld3;
```

gcc

```
.comm   ld1,16,16
.comm   ld2,32,32
.comm   ld3,48,32
```

clang

```
.type   ld1,@object             # @ld1
.comm   ld1,16,16
.type   ld2,@object             # @ld2
.comm   ld2,32,16
.type   ld3,@object             # @ld3
.comm   ld3,48,16
```

According to the [x86_64 ABI](https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/elf/x86_64-abi-0.99.pdf), the alignment should be 16. Why is gcc aligning the latter two structs on 32?

I am using gcc `Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04 9.3.0` and clang `10.0.0-4ubuntu1` on Ubuntu `20.04.1 LTS`.

Comment: Curious, why is the alignment size important for your code?

Comment: I am in the midst of writing a C compiler and was fixing a bug. I was linking some code compiled by my compiler with some code compiled with gcc and the linker reported: /usr/bin/ld: warning: alignment 16 of symbol `ld3' in test.o is smaller than 32. It's unimportant but I'm just just curious.

Comment: The compiler is free to overalign an object, when it is the one creating it. Gcc probably thinks that the extra alignment will help with performance in some cases (it could copy the whole ld2 object with a single aligned AVX move, in this translation unit). If you only declare the object with `extern`, gcc only assumes 16 as alignment.